# Round time in python odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I use below example for round time in odoo.

```
@api.one
@api.depends('start','finish','pause')
def total(self):
    for rec in self:
        time1 = datetime.strptime(rec.start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        time2 = datetime.strptime(rec.finish, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        rec.total_time = round(((time2 - time1).seconds / float(60*60) - self.pause))
```

For example:

if start = 07:57:21 , finish = 16:25:36, pause = 1  get result 7 hours

if start = 07:57:34 , finish = 16:28:42, pause = 1  get result 8 hours

First and second time different is 3 minutes but in result that is one hours!

How change round if total time >= 7 hours 30 minutes 01 second I need result 8 in other solution 7.5 (7 hours and 30 minutes)

Comment: `in other solution 7 or 7.5`?? Do you want 7 or 7.5?

Comment: `round(7.5)==8` and `round(7.4)==7==int(7.4)` and `round(7.6)==8==int(7.6+1)`

Comment: @julivico  Sorry my mistake, I'm edit question 7 hours 30 minutes 01 second I need result 8 in other solution 7.5 (7 hours and 30 minutes)

Comment: like that `round(7.5001) = 8`, `round(7.4)=7`, `round(7.5)=7.5` ?

Comment: @julivico Yes, I want this!

Comment: `if diff_time == 7.5:  res = 7.5;   else res = round(diff_time)`

Comment: if it is so, then it is much easier than make a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` you can use `DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT`

```
from odoo.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT
```

For your problem you can use `round(x, n)`. Example:

```
round(7.4, 0) = 7
round(7.5, 0) = 8
round(7.5, 1) = 7.5
```

Here you need `n = 1` for `7.5` and `n=0` for the 'standard' `round`. You can check `7.5` with `((7.5 - 0.5) % 1) == 0` and convert it from `boolean` to `int` directly with `int()`

The general solution is:

```
@api.one
@api.depends('start','finish','pause')
def total(self):
    for rec in self:
        time1 = datetime.strptime(rec.start, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
        time2 = datetime.strptime(rec.finish, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
        total_time = (time2 - time1).seconds / float(60*60) - self.pause
        rec.total_time = round(total_time, int(((total_time - 0.5) % 1) == 0))
```

Comment: Nice example, Is it possible use two options, eg.  total time >= 7 hours 30 minutes 00 second = 8 hours  and  total time < 7 hours 30 minutes 00 second = 7.5

Comment: Or `rount(2*total_time)/2.0`

Comment: @Anonymous: nice advice. But for `round(7.501*2)/2.0 = 7.5` which must be 8?

Comment: @Anonymousmiliana  I need this option!

Comment: @Anonymousmiliana: nice

Answer (score 1):

```
@api.one
@api.depends('start','finish','pause')
def total(self):
    for rec in self:
        time1 = datetime.strptime(rec.start, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
        time2 = datetime.strptime(rec.finish, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
        total_time = (time2 - time1).seconds / float(60*60) - self.pause
        total_time = 2*total_time
        if 2*total_time%1 <=0.5 :
            res = round(total_time)
        else :
            res = round(2*total_time)
        rec.total_time = res
```

Comment: Tnx for help, but after use your example I don't get correct result.